# Is there a bitcoin source, fork available that does not include a GUI?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

I would like to try to download and compile a barebones variation of the Bitcoin daemon.  Specifically, I'd would prefer to not have a copy of the code with any GUI implementation.

Does such a reliable, and maintained, forked project exist on Github or any where else?

Comment: Any reason why you don't want the GUI code at all? You can just compile bitcoind, which doesn't include the GUI or or any dependency on GUI libraries.

Comment: @PieterWuille: I'm looking for a clean codebase because I want to implement my own GUI interface.  In short, I want to start with "nothing".  Is bitcoind in a separate project, or will I need to weed out all of the unnecessary code from the github project?

Comment: The simple solution is go get the Github linux version meant to be compiled with QT and go over the dot pro file.  Consider it the ' build the program in to a GUI ' form of file with the added benifit of all the rest of the needed files in source directories.  I have had to do something similar for another currency just to get it to compile in Ubuntu.

Comment: Bitcoind is Bitcoin-Qt without the GUI code. It is in the same repository, but all GUI code is in the qt directory. Just ignore it if you want to.

Comment: @PieterWuille shouldn't you post your reply as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you compile the [bitcoin client](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) using the following commands, it will not build the GUI components:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --without-gui
make
```